# display unicode in smart phone?

Tags: java, android, xml, unicode, smartphone

this is my java activity

```
public class word extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
EditText et;
Button btnz,btncopy;
TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.word);
    et =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
    btnz =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnz);
    btncopy =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnc);
    tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    btnz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String a ="a";
            String b ="b";
            String c ="c";
            String d ="d";
            String e ="e";
            String f ="f";
            String g ="g";
            String h ="h";
            String a1 ="\u24B6";
            String b1 ="\u24B7";
            String c1 ="\u24B7";
            String d1 ="\u24B9";
            String e1 ="\u24BB";
            String f1 ="\u24BB";
            String g1 ="\u24BD";
            String h1 ="\u24BD";
            String name =et.getText().toString();
            name =name.replaceAll(a,a1);
            name =name.replaceAll(b,b1);
            name =name.replaceAll(c,c1);
            name =name.replaceAll(d,d1);
            name =name.replaceAll(e,e1);
            name =name.replaceAll(f,f1);
            name =name.replaceAll(g,g1);
            name =name.replaceAll(h,h1);
            tv.setText(name);
```

when run in avd and write in edittext it's working but when run in my smart phone dont display everything
i'm verey Effort and searching in internet.
what is solution?
i'm sorry for my grammar please Do not dismiss

Answer (score 0):

A character will never be displayed on-screen unless the font that you're using has a glyph for that character. Check what font the TextView is using, and then find out whether that font contains glyphs for characters like `"\u24B6"` (circled A = Ⓐ). If not, you'll need to use a different font.

Comment: @p.karimdost: Welcome to S.O. Can you provide some context for your comment link? The link points to a question on another web site about copying text with font, possibly posted by you. There is an answer there pointing to documentation on ClipData. So did it turn out that using the right font was indeed the problem? If my answer was correct and led you toward a solution, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark.